# Elastic Search - Filter data which match value along with data type

Tags: elasticsearch, types, aws-elasticsearch

I am using ES 5.7 of AWS. There is list of objects stored in elastic search cluster.Each object has one field status which value is integer, but because of one programmatic bug of indexer for some objects status value stored as text instead of integer. I need to filter the objects using bool query for which status is text.

I have used below query to filter the data.

sample data

```
{  
   "took":22,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":16,
      "successful":16,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":3208,
      "max_score":1,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"entity-data",
            "_type":"account",
            "_id":"b7b46c",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{  
               "status":"3"
            }
         },
         {  
            "_index":"entity-data",
            "_type":"account",
            "_id":"b7b46",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{  
               "status":3
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

bool query used to filter based on status

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "status": "3"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}

Here "status": "3" and "status": 3 is providing same result.
```

I need to filter data where "status": "3".

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide the mapping for this ES index? You can get it by executing `GET entity-data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script doesnt work since the mapping of the field would of type `long` and while doing the search using the script you wrote it only looks at the inverted index which is of type long.

You can use **painless** script ***to access the document values*** and find all the string values. The script checks the datatype of the field `status` and returns true only for String type's. Hence, it will return all documents containing String values.

```
PUT t1/doc/1
{
   "status": 3
}

PUT t1/doc/2
{
   "status": "3"
}



GET t1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "if(params._source.status instanceof String) return true;",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "t1",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "status": "3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Additional Information:**

If you want to ***change all those string values to long***, you can `reindex` into a new index and use script to manipulate the values.

```
//Create new index
PUT t2

//reindex from t1 to t2 and change string to integer
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "t1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "t2"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "if(ctx._source.status instanceof String){ctx._source.status = Integer.parseInt(ctx._source.status)}"
  }
}
```